# Renumber encrypted partition - sda3 to sda5

Tags: partition, lvm, luks

I have an encrypted `crypt-luks` partition that is currently named `sda3`, and is the last partition on the disk, that is, there are no `sda4` or `sda5`. The encrypted partition contains three logical volumes containing the filesystem.

Is there anyway I can rename the partition from `sda3` to `sda5`? This is a new installation, and I don't mind losing data. I'll be using a recovery USB stick to renumber the partition if this is at all possible.

I tried using `gdisk` with the advanced mode, and renamed the disk using the `t` option. Now however I cannot boot from the disk: It asks for the encryption password and loops back when entered. What is the correct way of doing this?

<sub>(For those curious, I need this is due to an automatic script that expects my encrypted partition to be on `sda5`. Unfortunately, the script is run at boot over a network, and I don't have control over it.)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is based on the forum posting [udev rule for a symlink](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=46844)

You have `/dev/sda3` and you want to create a symlink to it to synthesise an entry for the missing device named `/dev/sda5`:

```
cd /dev && ln -s sda3 sda5
```

This can be managed at boot time within `udev` with a simple rule that matches the block device `sda3`.

Create the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-local`, or use a similarly named file, and add these lines to it:

```
# symlink existing /dev/sda3 to new sda5
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sda3" SYMLINK+="sda5"
```

In case you're curious, I picked the `SUBSYSTEM` and `KERNEL` values as suitable matches by reviewing the output of `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sda3`. (I would have preferred to match on a UUID or other unique identifier but I couldn't find one.)

Now tell `udev` to reload its rules and trigger any new matches:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
udevadm trigger --attr-match=subsystem=block
```

and you will see the symlink automatically created:

```
ls -l /dev/sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    4 Jan  7 17:18 /dev/sda5 -> sda3
```

I have not been able to test this next step, but depending on where in the boot process you need this symlink to be created you may find it's necessary to update your `initramfs`. On my Debian system that's done like this:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: The last bits aren't really needed. Simply adding the udev rule and restarting the system are enough.

Comment: @nbubus yes a reboot would work too.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (but probably not the best) would be to just create a symbolic link.

```
ln -nsf /dev/sda3 /dev/sda5
```

EDIT: This will most likely get deleted on boot so you'll need to script this fairly early in the boot process

EDIT: Thanks to roaima in the comments the following udev rule should create the link automagically.  Create the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/82-cryptsetup.rules` with the following contents

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sda3", SYMLINK+="sda5"
```

Comment: Would that really work? The script in question tries to encrypt the disk. Would cryptsetup follow the link?

Comment: It should.  I've done this before but not for use with `cryptsetup`.  Other tools (`mkfs`, `tune2fs`, etc.) don't seem to mind.  `cryptsetup` just needs to be able to access the raw blocks which it can do through the symlink.

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting `device /dev/sda5 doesn't exist or access denied`.

Comment: Apparently this gets deleted on boot, since `/dev` gets created anew on every reboot.

Comment: Yup.  Sorry, I forgot to mention that part.

Comment: This forum posting [udev rule for a symlink](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=46844) may help

Comment: @roaima - care to add that as an answer?